# Reading raspberry terminal by SSH

Tags: python, linux

I have a server on raspberry and want to see what's happening in the terminal.

I'm connecting to raspberry by SSH. Connection is done but I don't see any changes which raspberry makes with by Python code, none of Python `print` are shown.

What do I need to do to see all the prints which are in the Python code?

Comment: Can you edit your question provide your code as part of your question!

Comment: When you say the terminal do you mean the main display you get by connecting a screen to the device directly? No, output printed there wouldn't go automatically go to you SSH connection too.

Comment: There is nothing like *the terminal*. There are many terminals and every single one has it's own input and output streams. If you connect you get an new terminal that is unrelated to terminals that are already open.

Comment: @Klaus D. Ok, I got. But is this possible to connect to already opened terminal?

Comment: Not to a normal one. But you can open a [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) session and resume it from an other terminal.